# nodejs terminal:console.log can't print

Tags: node.js, express

app.js

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  console.log('hhh');
});


io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
  socket.on('nickname',function(data){
    console.log('The sever received the following nickname: ' +data);
  });
});
```

index.html

```
<h1>Socket.IO Express Example</h1>


<form id="set-nickname">
      <label for="nickname">Nickname:</label>
      <input type="text" id="nickname">
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
   </form> 


<script src="http://lib.sinaapp.com/js/jquery/1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>




<script type="text/javascript">
   var socket = io.connect();
    jQuery(function($){
         var nickName = $('#nickname');
         var setNacknameForm = $('#set-nickname');
         setNacknameForm.submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefalut();
            socket.emit('nickname',nickName.val());
         });
      });   
   </script>
```

`hhh` can print in terminal [browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgIaT.png) but I enter words in browser, I click `submit`, nothing is printed in terminal.

I'm using express version 4.x

What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "I enter words"?

Comment: Your front end JS code is wrapped into a <script> tag no?

Comment: Are you sure the client is actually connected? How are you setting up socket.io with your Express application?

Comment: i use the <script> tag ,i click the code